# How to prevent data being overwritten? Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

At the moment the code I am using to upload multiple files and import the numeric data. But the code overwrites the previously selected files and just gives the data of the final selected file. Here is the code:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','MultiSelect','on');
numfiles = size(FileName,2);
for ii = 1:numfiles
    FileName{ii};
    A=[];
    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});
    fid = fopen(entirefile);
    tline = fgets(fid);
    while ischar(tline)
        parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');
        if numel(parts{1}) > 0
            A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];
        end
        tline = fgets(fid);
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
FileData = A
```

I realize if I put `A =[];` outside the `for loop` all data will be written into A and files wont be overwritten. However I would prefer to change my code so that the data from each file is in a seperate cell in the array A, how can I go about this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `A{ii}=[];`, then later `A{ii} = [ A{ii}; parts{:}' ];`

Comment: And, although not necessary, initiallize `A = cell(1,numfiles);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code `Filedata` is the cell having data from each file.

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','MultiSelect','on');
numfiles = size(FileName,2);
Filedata= cell(1,numfiles);
for ii = 1:numfiles
    FileName{ii};
    A=[];
    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});
    fid = fopen(entirefile);
    tline = fgets(fid);
    while ischar(tline)
        parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');
        if numel(parts{1}) > 0
            A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];
        end
        tline = fgets(fid);
    end
    fclose(fid);
    FileData{ii} = A;
end
```

You can iterate through the cell by using the following code

```
 for ii = 1:numfiles
 A = FileData{ii} ; %// A will be a 755x8 double matrix
 %// do something with A
 end
```

Comment: Thank you @Nishant, the result I get is `FileData =  [755x8 double]    [755x8 double]    [755x8 double]` how can I go about using one of these doubles? Or opening them to view the data?

Comment: should `Finaldata` be `FileData`? As that piece of code results in the error: `Undefined variable "Finaldata" or class "Finaldata". Error in multiselect (line 56) A = Finaldata{ii} ; %// A will be a 755x8 double matrix`

Comment: Yes you are right,it should be `Filedata`  I have edited the code in my answer , sorry for the mistake

Comment: Ok no problem, so should I set A as one of the `[755x8 double]` by using maybe `A = FileData(1,1)` when using that piece of code?

Comment: That piece of code sets `A` to one of `[755x8] double ` in the line `A = FileData{ii};` . In cells individual elements are accessed by `cell{index_i,index_j}`.